# How can I eliminate duplicate values where certain values intersect in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, data-analysis, data-mining

This is the 2005-2015 panel data between countries.

It's arranged as below.

year iso_i industry iso_j thetaij

2005 ARG D01T03 AUS  0

2005 AUS D01T03 ARG  0

There are two rows where year and industry are the same, and Iso_i and Iso_j intersect each other.
I want to see the two rows as duplicate rows and leave only one.

If you remove it based on this standard, there will be only half of the total number of rows left.

I figured out how to do it with an Excel macro file, but the total number of rows in the panel data is 480,000 and it doesn't work in Excel...

I think I'll have to do it at R.
Can you tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand, you don't care that the last 2 columns differ in these duplicate rows. If that's the case, this will work (just change `df` to the name of your data frame):

```
library(dplyr)
id <- which(duplicated(select(df, year, iso_i, industry))
length(id) # check number of duplicates
df<- df[-id,]
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be creating a new column pasting iso_i and iso_j fields in alphabetic order. That's what the `mutate` with `if_else` is doing. Grouping (`group_by`) will eliminate duplicated lines. The `summarise` is preserving the original data, supposing they are equal as you said (so just took the first element):

```
dt <- tibble(year = c(2005, 2005),
             iso_i = c("ARG", "AUS"),
             industry = c("D01T03", "D01T03"),
             iso_j = c("AUS", "ARG"),
             thetai_j = c(0, 0))
  
dt <- dt %>% 
  mutate(iso_ij = if_else(iso_i > iso_j, 
                          paste0(iso_j, iso_i, sep = " "),
                          paste0(iso_i, iso_j, sep = " "))) %>% 
  group_by(year, industry, iso_ij) %>% 
  summarise(thetai_j = first(thetai_j),
            iso_i = first(iso_i),
            iso_j = first(iso_j)) %>% 
  select(year, iso_i, industry, iso_j, thetai_j)

(dt)
```

Final `select` command is to preserve information in same order.